# how to interact asp.net application with web connector

Tags: quickbooks, connector

I am using QuickBooks web connector and i am trying to get company data. For that I created a service which is communicating with web connector and getting all the data.

What i tried so for:

1. I am selecting .qwc file using web connector. Just for testing am quiring only customer data and storing into notepad.

i am using asp.net application. From that application i will give the option to select to  the end user: like

1. Customers 2.vendors 3. items like check boxes. Based on the selection i have to get the related data using web connector.

MY problem is : how can i intercat my application to web connector...how can i get the data what end user is selcted from asp.net application.

Let me know if question is clear or not ....